# Check Style Indentation violation - 'public' have incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sonarqube, checkstyle

I am getting an checkstyle sonar violation on indendation rule (com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.indentation)

'public' have incorrect indentation level 4, expected level should be 8.

at this line

```
    public Response getItem(@PathParam(CODE) final ProgramCode programCode,
```

In Intelliji, Kindly suggest on how to change the indentation level to 8

Comment: Thomas, I have Updated the code.

Comment: A little late for this but for future readers it might be helpful: Auto indenting with Ctrl+Alt+L did the trick for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open up preferences (cmd + , on the Mac, ctrl + alt + s on Windows), and go to Editor -> Code Style -> Java. On the tabs and indents spaces you can set the indents to 8.

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to indentation; that is:

If U have applied some checkstyle then you may not follow its rule simply click Ctrl + Shift + F (Auto Format).

Answer (score 0):

You can add your check-style.xml here. After this you can use macOS[⌥+⌘+L] or Windows[Ctrl+Alt+L] [Reformat code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_code) [image]