# Code Analysis For Android using Checkstyle

Tags: android, checkstyle

I am checking my code using FindBugs, PMD and Checkstyle for improving the codebase and identify potential vulnerabilities along with design flaws. But i am facing trouble in finding out what exactly is the problem ? I have used Lambda expression in my Code.

**Error Description**

```
'member def modifier' have incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 4.   34
'member def modifier' have incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 4.   37
'member def modifier' have incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 4.   39
'method def modifier' have incorrect indentation level 8, expected level should be 4.   42
'method def' child have incorrect indentation level 16, expected level should be 8. 44
'method def' child have incorrect indentation level 16, expected level should be 8. 46
'method def' child have incorrect indentation level 16, expected level should be 8. 47
'method def' child have incorrect indentation level 16, expected level should be 8. 48
'method def' child have incorrect indentation level 16, expected level should be 8. 50
'method def' child have incorrect indentation level 16, expected level should be 8. 52
```

**RegisterActivity**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity implements LifecycleOwner {

        @Inject :**line number 34**
        public RegisterViewModel mRegisterViewModel;

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog; **line number 37**

        private ActivityRegisterBinding mBinding;
```

> I have added my Activity which shows error at the certain line, but i
>   am not able to find out what exactly is the problem in my Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using indentation as specified in the error log?

Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31835496/5053322)

[I meant to comment but due to lack of reputation I was denied that privilege.so, I had to post an answer]

Comment: i am not able to understand the exact error log message.what does it meant to tell??can you explain it please

Comment: okay, let's take the first statement of your log, specifying indentation issue on line no 34. it means at that particular line, there are 8 white space before actual code, and it wants you to make it 4. Just delete the 4 white spaces. Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the java indentation violation, I dnt think that will make any impact in the project.. 
Solution referred by @themrhornet [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31835496/5740236)! should work since android IDE have their own rules

Open up preferences (cmd + , on the Mac, ctrl + alt + s on Windows), and go to Editor -> Code Style -> Java. On the tabs and indents spaces you can set the indents to 8.